# How right render div in nested array in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I got a JSON. Something like

```
[ 
  {title: 'First', price: [124, 254, 236]},
  {title: 'Second', price: [1244, 24, 23]},
]
```

And I want to write render function, which'll create table, consist of div like title from array and nested table consist of prices.

How do right to write this code from Big O point.

Easy way it'is do like this

```
const nestedTable = (j) => j.map(g => <div>{g}</div>);
const table = arr.map(i => <>{i.title} - {nestedTable(i.price)}</>);
```

But I think it's not best practice.

Can you show the best way.

Comment: what u think about `[...i.price].toString()`

Comment: @LeoLima, I don't understend what you mean

Comment: `const table = arr.map(i => <>{i.title} - {[...i.price].toString()}</>);`